# onPostExecute on cancelled AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Does `onPostExecute` execute if the `AsyncTask` has been cancelled?

If it does execute, is it safe to say that I should always ask if the task has been cancelled (`isCancelled`) at the start of `onPostExecute`, before doing anything else?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10163763/165674).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The documented behaviour of onPostExecute on cancel() was changed between Android 2 and Android 4.

[Android 2.3.7 onPostExecute](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.onPostExecute%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. The specified result is
>   the value returned by doInBackground or null if the task was cancelled
>   or an exception occured.

[Android 4.0.1 onPostExecute](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.onPostExecute%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. The specified result is
>   the value returned by doInBackground. This method won't be invoked if
>   the task was cancelled.

So if you are still targeting Android 2 devices you should assume that onPostExecute will be called and in onPostExecute check for null result.

Comment: Extremely useful answer!

Comment: onCancelled will be called if you cancel the asynctask

Answer (score 8):

From my experience the onPostExecute() is actually not invoked when the task is cancelled. However, it may be possible to cancel the task after the task's doInBackground() is finished but before the onPostExecute() is invoked - in this case the onPostExecute() is actually invoked. Therefore, to be sure, I call the isCancelled() method in onPostExecute() and just "return" if the task has been cancelled. It works for me.

Comment: Is it really true? I mean - how can I reproduce it? Any test code or idea on this?

Comment: **_"Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never subsequently invoked"_** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29

Answer (score 7):

After checking the AsyncTask source code it seems that onPostExecute is invoked even if the task is cancelled. However, before calling onPostExecute the result is set to null (?) if the task has been cancelled.

Edit: @bain provides an updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301904/143378).