# AysncTask cancelling itself still calls onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

After calling `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` from within `doInBackground()`, instead of calling  `onCancelled()`, Android calls `onPostExecute()`. But [as per the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29):

> Calling this method will result in `onCancelled(Object)` being invoked
>   on the UI thread after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. **Calling this
>   method guarantees that `onPostExecute(Object)` is never invoked**.

Is it a bug in Android?

**More Observations:**

1. Calling `cancel(false)` from either thread works as specified in the
   documentation.
2. Calling `cancel(true)` from the UI task does *not* call `onPostExecute()`, nor does it throw the `InterruptedException` seen in the logcat traces below.
3. Calling `cancel(false/true)` from any thread sometimes calls `onCancelled()` even before `doInBackground()` returns. This is clearly in violation of the documentation, [which states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29):

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread **after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns**.

**Code:** (Tested on Android 2.2 device)

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d(TAG, "started doInBackground()");
    while (!isCancelled()) {
        boolean ret = cancel(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "cancel() returned: " + ret);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "returning from doInBackground()");
    return null;
}
```

**Logcat output**

```
04-15 21:38:55.519: D/MyTask(27597): started doInBackground()
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597): java.lang.InterruptedException
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1254)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:219)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:82)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:196)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerCancel(FutureTask.java:293)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:75)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at android.os.AsyncTask.cancel(AsyncTask.java:325)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at com.example.test.TestActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(TestActivity.java:31)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at com.example.test.TestActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(TestActivity.java:1)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-15 21:38:55.589: W/AsyncTask(27597):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-15 21:38:55.589: D/MyTask(27597): cancel() returned: true
04-15 21:38:55.589: D/MyTask(27597): returning from doInBackground()
04-15 21:38:55.659: D/MyTask(27597): onPostExecute()
```

Comment: Why would you want to cancel an `AsyncTask` from within `doInBackground`? That doesn't make sense. The `cancel(...)` method is deliberately meant to allow code outside of the worker thread (in other words on the UI thread) to halt execution. If code in `doInBackground` needs to terminate itself for whatever reason then it should simply `return`. If you don't want `onPostExecute(...)` to perform certain actions as a result of a pseudo-cancel then return `false` otherwise return `true`

Comment: @MisterSquonk, "The cancel(...) method is deliberately meant to allow code outside of the worker thread to halt execution." The documentation does not say it's to be called only from the UI thread. Why not reuse the existing code of `onCancelled()` instead of using unsightly workarounds?

Comment: Agreed, the documentation doesn't say that it should be called only from the UI thread but that seems most logical. The reason I say that is the documentation does say that `doInBackground` should periodically check `isCancelled()` to see if it needs to halt its own execution (as a result of a call to `cancel`). If having `doInBackground` call `cancel` is normal then what would be the point of `isCancelled()`?

Comment: @MisterSquonk, fair enough. Still why this artificial weird behavior? Also, I've added point #3 under 'More Observations'.

Comment: I've been looking at the source for `AsyncTask` for Android v2.2 here...http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/AsyncTask.java?av=f but I can't come up with an answer. I can see that `AsyncTask` uses `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask` which is what throws the exception you posted. I can't find the source for it at the moment though. I suspect there is a small bug somewhere and I agree it would be good to use `onCancelled` elegantly. Perhaps writing your own version of `AsyncTask` might be the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is an exception because you call cancel(true) which sends an interrupt to the thread running doInBackground() - however, in this case, you are calling cancel(true) from within doInBackground(), thus causing the thread to immediately send an interrupt to itself.
2. Your code is running on Android 2 but you are quoting the docs for Android 4. The problem is that the behaviour on cancel() changed between Android 2 and Android 4.

   [Android 2.3.7 onPostExecute](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.onPostExecute%28java.lang.Object%29) :

   > Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. The specified result is
   >   the value returned by doInBackground or null if the task was cancelled
   >   or an exception occured.

   [Android 4.0.1 onPostExecute](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.onPostExecute%28java.lang.Object%29) :

   > Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground. The specified result is
   >   the value returned by doInBackground. This method won't be invoked if
   >   the task was cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You should return null and treat the return in the onPostExecute.