# AsyncTask cancel(Boolean) calls onPostExecute -?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [onPostExecute on cancelled AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334858/onpostexecute-on-cancelled-asynctask)

Why does cancelling a `AsyncTask` still calls `onPostExecute` if the docs say it should call `onCancelled` instead.
Is this a long persistent bug?

In my case it I `cancel(true)` the asynctask, it finishes the `doInBackground` and then invokes onPostExecutes.
Finally it throws a

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
```

If this is intented behavour, can I get this `Exception` anyhow as an object?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334858/onpostexecute-on-cancelled-asynctask

Comment: actually asynk task dont get cancelled instantly . to make this really cancel you have to do some work and check it whether cancel is called or not using flag concept

Comment: yep gunnar this is what I'm experiencing. so this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation from the cancel() method you'll find this:

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
>   the task has already completed, already been cancelled, or could not
>   be cancelled for some other reason.

calling cancel() will set isCancelled() to true. Are you periodically checking the return value of this method in your doInBackground?

```
   protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {  
   while (/* condition */) { 
      // work...    
   if (isCancelled()) break; 
    }    
 return null;  }
```

As for the exception, java.lang.InterruptedException   , there could be multiple reasons.

My guess in your case is that you may be calling cancel() at a wrong place/time, and  you may not be checking for isCancelled() periodically in doInBackground, so the task is completed suceessfully and onPostExecute() is called.

Answer (score 1):

After `onPostExecute` should be calls `onCancelled`

Comment: there are definitly no calls on onCancelled(), only if I stop with cancel(false)